# Trigger doesn't work (if statement)

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a problem. I want to create a trigger.

```
    DELIMITER $
    Create trigger xyz
    before delete on worker
    FOR EACH ROW
    Begin
    IF salary>2000
    then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Zakaz usuwania';
    end if;
    End$
    DELIMITER ;

delete from pracownik where id=5
```

I get an error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'salary' in 'where clause'

Comment: We need a little more information to know exactly what is going on here. It looks like you're missing a column or have a misnamed column in your trigger. There may also be other issues, but I can't be sure, because you haven't told us what database type you're using. If you can add the tags for the appropriate database type, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hint:  `new.salary`.